# При запуске pgAdmin 4 выдает ошибку The application server could not be contacted

Tags: sql, postgresql

При запуске pgAdmin выдает ошибку

> The application server could not be contacted

но если запустит `pgAdmin 3` все загружается,

При повторном запуске `pgAdmin 4` этой ошибки нет,все загружается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перезапустите службу postgres.

Comment: не помогло :-( `%APPDATA%\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.log` пустой, при удалении этой папки она создается заново.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю поможет ли это кому-то, но всё же напишу тут, дорогой читатель. Если не помогли такие методы, как:
-попробуйте запустить PgAdmin отмени администратора.
-добавьте путь к bin-папке Postgresql в переменные окружения.
-очистите папку C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin
-перезапустите службу

То проверьте имя и описание своего компьютера, если заданы значения на русском, то измените их на латинские буквы, затем всё полностью удалите и переустановите, мне помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Win7_x64 pgAdmin 4.21 - при такой ошибке помогло задать латинское имя компьютера, с перезагрузкой